# Calculating pre-tax cost of debt

Tags: fixed-income

This is a simple problem but I'm not sure about one aspect of it.

A company has 15 year bonds outstanding, with a 5% annual coupon, a face value of \$1000, and a current market value of \$1100.  What is the company's pre-tax cost of debt?

I'm tempted to think it's just 5%, as when the company originally sold the bonds it received $1000 and is paying 5% coupons on that original face value, but the inclusion of the current market value is confusing me.  I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Wild guess: CFA Level I question?

Comment: @SRKX Exactly what ran through my head when I read it - that's why I included the accounting bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple TVM problem - solve for the interest rate.  The "current" cost of debt would be market determined, so that's why you use the market value.  It ties into how bond accounting works - the premium of the bond is amortized until maturity.  The amortization amount would be the difference between the coupon and the interest expense(market rate at issuance)

Comment: So I'm just calculating the YTM?

Comment: @CooperRoyce Unless I misunderstood the question, yes.